# How to calculate angle between two planes?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js, rotation

I have two planes, how can I calculate angle between them? Is it also possible to calculate angle between two Object3D points like in case of planes?

Heres an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rsu842v8/1/

```js
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(25, 25, 12);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00fff0,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  window.plane1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10), material);
  scene.add(plane1);

  plane1.position.set(0.3, 1, -2);
  plane1.rotation.set(Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 2, 1);

  window.plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0fff00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  }));
  scene.add(plane2);


  // setup rest
  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
  pointLight.position.x = 10;
  pointLight.position.y = 50;
  pointLight.position.z = 130;
  scene.add(pointLight)

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x20252f);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  animate();

  // TODO: What is the angle between plane1 and plane2?

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r82/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://yume.human-interactive.org/examples/buffer-geometry/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no such term as angle between two points. Perhaps you mean something else...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to find the angle between two three.js plane meshes.

Unrotated, a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` is oriented to face the positive z-axis. So the plane's normal points in the direction of the positive z-axis.

So, create a ( 0, 0, 1 ) vector, and apply the same rotation to it as is applied to the plane mesh.

Note that `plane.quaternion` is automatically updated when you set `plane.rotation`, so you can use the quaternion in the calculation -- like so:

```
var vec1 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ); // create once and reuse
var vec2 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );

vec1.applyQuaternion( plane1.quaternion );
vec2.applyQuaternion( plane2.quaternion );

var angle = vec1.angleTo( vec2 ); // radians
```

The problem is a bit more complicated if the planes are children of other rotated objects.

Of course, you can use `angleTo()` to find the angle between any two vectors.

three.js r.86

Comment: That is great! Only problem i had with this solution is that angle is in radians (which I was kind of expecting). So i converted them with `THREE.Math.radToDeg`. Heres fiddle with solution: https://jsfiddle.net/rsu842v8/3/

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest somehow calculating the normal vectors for each plane you are rendering. Once you have these two vectors - let's say `n1` and `n2` - it is easy to calculate the angle between the planes with the dot product.

If you aren't familiar with the dot product, `dot(n1,n2)` where `n1 = (x1,y1,z1)` and `n2 = (x2,y2,z2)` would be equal to `x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2`. There is another simple identity that says `dot(n1,n2) = |v1||v2|cos(a)` where `||` indicates the magnitude of a vector - i.e. `|v| = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` if `v = (x,y,z)` - and a is the angle between the normals which is the angle between the planes. Here is a link to a [Mathematics Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528909/find-the-angle-between-two-planes-using-their-normal-vectors).

In short `a = arccos(dot(n1,n2) / |n1||n2|)`.

If you are interested in learning more about how planes are defined and what the normal vector represents try looking at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html).

If you know `n1` and `n2` are [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) then the equation simplifies further to `a = arccos(dot(n1,n2))`.